# Mínimo común múltiplo entre un intervalo de numeros(1 al 20)

Tags: python

Un profesor me ha puesto la tarea de encontrar en python el mínimo número que sea divisible entre todos los números entre el 1 al 20.
Mi código es este y no consigo entender por qué no funciona:

```
numero_inicial = 1

while True:
    for numero in range(2,21):

        if numero_inicial % numero != 0:
            numero_inicial += 1
            break
            
        else:
            pass

        if numero == 20:
            print("Numero :")
            print(numero_inicial)
```

En la pantalla debería aparecer el número ya que está sumando un numero cada vez hasta encontrar el correcto pero al ejecutar no aparece ningún número

Comment: por qué dices que no funciona? qué dato usas para probar y cuál es el resultado?

Comment: El problema es que cuando le doy a ejecutar no aparece ningún numero y en teoría debería aparecer porque va sumando 1 hasta llegar al resultado correcto

Comment: Solo va a pintar un número con ese código , estás diciendo que cuando es igual a 20 pinte por pantalla , tienes que hacerlo para todos los números que sean multiplo

Comment: Creo que no entiendo lo que dices. El objetivo es que la variable "numero" del for vaya a dividir a "numero_inicial".Cuando el "numero_inicial" sea el correcto y el "numero" del for lo haya dividido por todos los numeros del 1 al 20. Ahí es cuando imprime el número.

Comment: El if que has escrito causa un break cuando numero_inicial no es divisible entre numero. Ya que numero_inicial es 1, la condición se cumple nada mas empezar, y el break hace salir del bucle.

Comment: Ya saldría del for con el break y volvería a entrar con un numero más

Comment: hola, el problema ya esta resuelto. El código estaba bien pero al ser un numero tan grande "232.792.560" tardaba mucho en calcularlo y no me di cuenta jajaja. Gracias por la ayuda aun asi!!

Comment: @Daniel no es correcto colocar resuelto en el título de tu pregunta, si tienes la solución entonces lo recomendado es que publiques como respuesta la solución

Comment: El código está bien la respuesta es 232.792.560